# ssrs: Group field without messing up the table

Tags: ssrs-2012

In a table I have a repeating field that I want to group by but without messing up the table.

The data I have is the following:

[image]

and i want to get to this:

[image]

As you can see, group A is repeated and it's what I want. The problem is that it groups all the cities A into a single group and the table is messed up. Can you help me?

Comment: Is that all the data you have or is there something that can order the data such as a row number etc? You can do what you need but having a row number or some way of ordering the data as per your example is required otherwise you cannot guarantee the order of data data going into the report dataset query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment you will need something to order the rows by then it's a rather clunky solution to get what you need. There will probably be a much more elegant way but this will work.

The script reproduces you data, adds a row id and adds a groupid column.

You can use the group ID column to group your data by in the report even if it's not visible.

```
declare @t TABLE(client varchar(10), product varchar(10), [value] int, city varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('A', 'ASD', 13, 'A'),
('B', 'QWE', 40, 'A'),
('G', 'SDF', 31, 'A'),
('F', 'ERT', 12, 'B'),
('D', 'DFG', 2, 'B'),
('G', 'GFHJ', 4, 'C'),
('B', 'TY', 13, 'C'),
('V', 'URTY', 29, 'A'),
('C', 'ERT', 33, 'A')

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #r
CREATE  TABLE #r (client varchar(10), product varchar(10), [value] int, city varchar(10), RowID int IDENTITY(1,1), GroupID int)

-- this just adds a sort order for the data as #r has an identity column
INSERT INTO #r (client, product, [value], city) 
    SELECT client, product, [value], city FROM @t 

-- some variables to track the previous city and group counter
DECLARE @g int = 0 -- counter for row group
DECLARE @prvCity varchar(10) ='' -- previous city

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #r WHERE GroupID IS NULL) -- for any rows not updated
    BEGIN -- put the rowid into @r and city into @curCity
        declare @r int = (SELECT MIN(RowID) FROM #r WHERE GroupID is null)
        declare @curCity varchar(10) = (SELECT city from #r WHERE RowID = @r)

        IF @prvCity != @curCity -- if the city changed
            BEGIN 
                SET @g = @g + 1 -- increment the group
                SET @prvCity = @curCity -- set previous city to current city
            END

        UPDATE #r SET GroupID = @g WHERE RowID = @r -- update the temp table
    END

-- final output dataset query
SELECT * FROM #r
```

Here is the report design including the row groups

[image]

and here is the final output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Alan for your help!!

I tell you that I have, in addition to those fields, a "date" field that is the field by which the table is ordered.

Comment: I wanted to replicate what you gave me but when in the rowgroup I drag the GroupId field up in the table it appears grouped by this field and not by City.

Comment: Thank you very much Alan! 
I was able to do what you gave me and that clarified my doubt about how to do it. I replaced the GroupId field with the Date field I had and hid it so it doesn't show. Thank you so much for everything! A cordial greeting from Argentina!

Comment: Yes, sorry I forget to mention that I had just swapped out the field in the GroupID column. In SSRS it's quite easy to group by one field but display another. Anyway, glad you got it fixed.